# Unable to apply border to Table td

Tags: css, html-table

I must be overlooking something and I can seem to figure it out. I applied borders to my table cells and they are not showing. Please can someone take a look at the markup and css below and help me out. Here is the [static site](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15447938/BillDueDate/index.html) I have applied the Myers CSS reset to my stylesheet, not sure if it makes a difference.

```
<table>
                <caption>Your Upcoming Bill Due Dates</caption>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th scope="col"></th>
                    <th scope="col">Bill Due Date</th>
                    <th scope="col">Bill Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Amount</th>
                    <th scope="col">Frequency</th>
                    <th scope="col">Last Paid</th>
                </thead>                    
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>March 7th, 2013</td>
                    <td>Childcare</td>
                    <td>$560</td>
                    <td>Weekly</td>
                    <td>February 26th, 2013</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>June 13th, 2013</td>
                    <td>Water Bill</td>
                    <td>$125.60</td>
                    <td>Monthly</td>
                    <td>May 2nd, 2013</td>
                </tr>

            </table>
```

And here is the CSS

```
table {
    clear: both;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    border-collapse: separate;

}

td th {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could change `border-collapse:collapse;` to `border-spacing:0;`, but

> td th {
>       border: 2px solid red; }

should be written so

```
td ,th {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Comment: why border-spacing ? see to give border-radius to table, or borders to tr with & without

Comment: Yes sir, I just wanted to help clarify. It's also repeated in the other answer.

Comment: @GCyrillus Thank you so much, that was it. This is a practice site, so I am applying all styles to get see what each do before removing them. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your code there is an error on:

```
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th scope="col"></th>
                <th scope="col">Bill Due Date</th>
                <th scope="col">Bill Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Amount</th>
                <th scope="col">Frequency</th>
                <th scope="col">Last Paid</th>
            </thead>  /* HERE  */                  
            </tr>

            IT MUST BE

            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th scope="col"></th>
                <th scope="col">Bill Due Date</th>
                <th scope="col">Bill Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Amount</th>
                <th scope="col">Frequency</th>
                <th scope="col">Last Paid</th>
                </tr>                 
            </thead>
```

Also change `td th {` with `td,th {`

Comment: well seen ! that matters too +1

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, you need to add a `,` between `td` and `th`, otherwise it's only looking to apply the style to `th` which are children of `td`:

```
td, th {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Also, your HTML is a little out of order - the `</thead>` is before the closing `</tr>`.  You've also specified a `<thead>` but no `<tbody>`...

Comment: Thanks, this site is a work in progress, I am planning to add tbody shortly, I just adding the elements one at a time to see visually what each does